# HighChart mouseOut issue in react-native-webview

Tags: reactjs, react-native, highcharts, react-native-webview

We were facing an issue with the functionality of plotOptions. Our requirement is when user has it's finger away from the column bar we have to show a text. This works properly in browser but when integrated this Url in react-native-webview this feature does not work.

Adding the code snippet for your reference :

```
plotOptions: {

series: {

point: {

events: {

mouseOver(e) {

setLine(e.target.index);

settotalAmount(e.target.options.y);

const { year } = array[e.target.index];

setcicTitle(`${e.target.category} ${year}`);

},

mouseOut() {

setLine(-1);

settotalAmount(parseFloat(array.totalCash));

setcicTitle('12 months');

},

},

},

},

}
```

*Please find the version used to implement this are below:*

**"highcharts": "9.0.1",
"highcharts-react-official": "3.0.0"
"react-native-webview": "7.0.5",**

Is there any way we can have this feature work in react-native-webview.